# Textarea validation with OR statement

Tags: jquery, textarea

I have a problem that I just can't understand. I would like to check if my Textarea field with id #message  is filled correctly before submission. 
I want to check if either value will be less than 1 OR has let's say value "p" THEN cancel submission but it's not working with OR statement. What am I doing wrong? I would really appreciate any kind of help.

```
 $("form").submit(function() {
    if (!$("#message").val().trim().length < 1 || $("#message").val("p") ) // if value will  NOT be less than 1  OR has value p     
    {
        alert("Thank you for sending the message. You should receive confirmation in your mailbox shortly.");
    }
    else {
        $("#labelTextArea").text("Provide a message!").css("color", "red"); 
        $("#message").focus(); //  focus element 
        event.preventDefault();// if msg is clear then error and cancel submission
    }
 });
```

Comment: $("#message").val().trim().length is not value. It length of value.

Comment: You can check value for your mentioned condition like this: `$("#message").val() == 1 || $("#message").val() == 'p'`

Comment: It works ! Thanks for help!

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
function validateMyForm() {

   if ($("#message").val().trim().length > 0 && $("#message").val().trim() == 'p' ) // if value will  NOT be less than 1  OR has value p 

    {
    alert("Thank you for sending the message. You should receive confirmation on your mailbox shortly.");
} else {
    $("#labelTextArea").text("Provide a message!").css("color", "red"); 
    $("#message").focus(); //  focus element 
    event.preventDefault();// if msg is clear then error and cancel submission
}
}
```

Comment: @MilanChheda - Your help were incorrect. $("#message").val() == 1 is not even correct logic. He was not checking equal value.